# `boost::multi_index_container` in shared memory?

Tags: boost, shared-memory, multi-index, boost-multi-index

I would be interested in something like a multi index container in shared memory.

Is it possible to allocate, e.g., a `boost::multi_index_container` in shared memory, so that different executables can read/write its data? How?

Thank's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've [googled](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/interprocess.html#interprocess.intro)...

Boost.Interprocess seems to fit. From [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/interprocess/allocators_containers.html#interprocess.allocators_containers.containers_explained.containers_of_containers) page:

> The widely used Boost.MultiIndex library is compatible with Boost.Interprocess so we can construct pretty good databases in shared memory.